# Image Magick watermark problem (upgrade 6.5.1 -> 6.5.7)

Tags: image, imagemagick, resize, watermark

We recently upgraded our version of image magick from 6.5.1 to 6.5.7 (via karmic->lucid ubuntu upgrade).

One of the commands we rely on is resizing an image and then placing it on top of another image:

```
composite -gravity 'Center' -resize '304x202!' watermark.png -size '320x213' base.jpg result.jpg
```

In this example we are expecting a result image of '320x213' pixel, with a '302x202' pixel version of 'watermark.png' placed over 'base.jpg' in the center.

This worked fine in image magick 6.5.1, but in version 6.5.7 our visual test fails as you can see below:

[alt text http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/2023/screenshot20100623at104.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/2023/screenshot20100623at104.png)

This looks like the '-size' options gets completely ignored for some reason, but any ideas would be appreciated!